# "Could not connect to device" error with a HDM LG2100 EVDO modem

Tags: modem, 3g

I an using Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't connect to the internet using wvdial and my modem HDM LG 2100 EVDO from INWI ISP. I get something like

```
Could not connect to device /dev/ttyUSB1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command

```
sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

After this, edit the file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

To add the phone number from your ISP.